# Getting a value of a field from another ejb

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I want to get a value of field in another ejb
here's my example i want to get the value of the "CLient" from the class (Visite) and get it in "ClientVisite" in the class (DateVisite) than persist this value in the database.

here's my code

```
package model.entitie;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import model.entitie.Visite;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Datevisite.findAll", query = "select o from Datevisite o") })
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DateVisite_Id_Seq_Gen", sequenceName = "DATEVISITE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1,
                   initialValue = 50)
public class Datevisite implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -341535626783197699L;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 4000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DateVisite_Id_Seq_Gen")
    private String iddatevis;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date jourvisite;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "VISITE_ID")
    private Visite datevisite;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "JOURVISITEEND")
    private Date jourvisteend;
    @Column(name = "DESCRPTION")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "CLIENTVISITE")
    private String ClientVisite;


    public void setClientVisite(String ClientVisite) {

        this.ClientVisite = ClientVisite;

    }

    public String getClientVisite() {
        return ClientVisite;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setJourvisteend(Date jourvisteend) {
        this.jourvisteend = this.jourvisite;
    }

    public Date getJourvisteend() {
        return jourvisteend;
    }

    public Datevisite() {
    }

    public Datevisite(String iddatevis, Date jourvisite, Visite datevisite, String ClientVisite) {
        this.iddatevis = iddatevis;
        this.jourvisite = jourvisite;
        this.datevisite = datevisite;

        this.ClientVisite = ClientVisite;

    }

    public String getIddatevis() {
        return iddatevis;
    }

    public void setIddatevis(String iddatevis) {
        this.iddatevis = iddatevis;
    }

    public Date getJourvisite() {
        return jourvisite;
    }

    public void setJourvisite(Date jourvisite) {
        this.jourvisite = jourvisite;
    }


    public Visite getDatevisite() {
        return datevisite;
    }

    public void setDatevisite(Visite datevisite) {
        this.datevisite = datevisite;
    }
}
```

the Visite CLass

```
 package model.entitie;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

    @Entity
    @NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Visite.findAll", query = "select o from Visite o") })
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Visite_Id_Seq_Gen", sequenceName = "VISITE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 50)
    public class Visite implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2402539910369717472L;
        @Column(length = 4000)
        public String client;
        @Column(length = 4000)
        private String dep;
        @Id
        @Column(nullable = false, length = 4000)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Visite_Id_Seq_Gen")
        private String idvisite;
        @Column(length = 4000)
        private String nbvisites;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "datevisite", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
        private List<Datevisite> datevisiteList;

        public Visite() {
        }

        public Visite(String client, String dep, String idvisite, String nbvisites) {
            this.client = client;
            this.dep = dep;
            this.idvisite = idvisite;
            this.nbvisites = nbvisites;
        }

        public String getClient() {
            return client;
        }

        public void setClient(String client) {

            this.client = client;
        }

        public String getDep() {
            return dep;
        }

        public void setDep(String dep) {
            this.dep = dep;
        }

        public String getIdvisite() {
            return idvisite;
        }

        public void setIdvisite(String idvisite) {
            this.idvisite = idvisite;
        }

        public String getNbvisites() {
            return nbvisites;
        }

        public void setNbvisites(String nbvisites) {
            this.nbvisites = nbvisites;
        }

        public List<Datevisite> getDatevisiteList() {
            return datevisiteList;
        }

        public void setDatevisiteList(List<Datevisite> datevisiteList) {
            this.datevisiteList = datevisiteList;
        }

        public Datevisite addDatevisite(Datevisite datevisite) {
            getDatevisiteList().add(datevisite);
            datevisite.setDatevisite(this);
            return datevisite;
        }

        public Datevisite removeDatevisite(Datevisite datevisite) {
            getDatevisiteList().remove(datevisite);
            datevisite.setDatevisite(null);
            return datevisite;
        }
    }
```

and this is how i persist it

```
    public Datevisite persistDatevisite(Datevisite datevisite) {
    datevisite.setJourvisteend(datevisite.getJourvisite());

    em.persist(datevisite);
    return datevisite;
}
```

Comment: You mean another "Entity" instead of "EJB" right? EJBs are the services/session beans. Just for clarification. Besides that, what did you try? Where are your problems?

Comment: yeah i mean it i tried public void setClientVisite(String ClientVisite,Visite visite) {

        this.ClientVisite = visite.getClient();

    } and nothing happend

Comment: Besides the fact that you have 2 parameters but use only one, it should work if the entity is attached. Does it work when you set a hard coded string? Must be the same place otherwise it could be attached in one place and detached in another.

Comment: that's just a String, how come attached and detached objects have effects here ? ... @user3419507 t'arrives à expliquer en français, ce sera plus simple ?

Comment: From your question, it is very unclear what you are doing and what went wrong. When you put a breakpoint right before `em.persist(datevisite)`, is datevisite.ClientVisite set to desired value? If not, you have problem in your code and not in JPA.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it right, you need to get client field from Visite class (visite.getClient()) and set it in clientVisite field from DateVisite class (datevisite.setClientVisite()), right ?

your DateVisite class already has a member visite, the code below should work for you :

```
datevisite.setClientVisite(datevisite.getDateVisite().getClient());
```